# The system cannot find the path specified:

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Following is my code to read a dicom file , But I am having issue in reading the file , any help will be appreciated

```
<import cv2
import pydicom as dicom            # for reading dicom files
import os                          # for doing directory operations 
import pandas as pd                # for some simple data 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimage
import numpy as np

data_dir = r'D:\project\New folder\LungNoduleDetectionClassification-master'
patients = os.listdir(data_dir)
labels_df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\project\New folder\LungNoduleDetectionClassification-master\stage1_labels.csv', index_col=0)

labels_df.head()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for patient in patients[:1]:
    path = data_dir + patient
    slices = [dicom.read_file(path + '/' + s) for s in os.listdir(path)]
    slices.sort(key = lambda x: int(x.ImagePositionPatient[2]))

    plt.imshow(slices[0].pixel_array)
    plt.show()>

Error :-

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-0cdfa4febaf1> in <module>
      3 for patient in patients[:1]:
      4     path = data_dir + patient
----> 5     slices = [dicom.read_file(path + '/' + s) for s in os.listdir(path)]
      6     slices.sort(key = lambda x: int(x.ImagePositionPatient[2]))
      7 

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'D:\\project\\New folder\\LungNoduleDetectionClassification-master1-001.dcm'
```

## note 1-001.dcm is a dicom file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your combination of directory name and filename is problematic:

```python
data_dir = r'D:\project\New folder\LungNoduleDetectionClassification-master'
patients = os.listdir(data_dir)
...
for patient in patients[:1]:
    path = data_dir + patient
```

This will mean `path` contains the directory name and the filename without a directory separator to separate them.

Generally, you want to do something like this to ensure the two are combined correctly:

```python
    path = os.path.join(data_dir, patient)
```